# To create a button with "load more" on power bi

Tags: button, powerbi

I need to create a button with "load more" on a table that has to load more data to the display. is that possible with any of the DAX query

I can apply on

That needs to be something like this :

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/images/load-more/flutter-datagrid-load-more-button.gifhttps://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/images/load-more/flutter-datagrid-load-more-button.gif

Please help me with this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/datagrid/images/load-more/flutter-datagrid-load-more-button.gif The link to it if you can't be able to open

Comment: No, this is not supported. Power BI is not a fancy web site builder.